# Does Jetpack conflicts with load_template()?

Tags: plugin-jetpack

**EDIT** *the title of this question was "Does anyone know if Jetpack is caching pages/content" but has been changed following the thread.*

I just updated a plugin I made.
Among others, it does filter the content of a page using `the_content` hook.

But I noticed that it does not behaves like it should once I pushed the changes online (some parts of my content are missing).

Once I do disable Jetpack, it works as expected.

Does anyone know if Jetpack is caching pages/content and how to clear that cache ?

I didn't find anything about it online.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

> Does anyone know if Jetpack is caching pages/content

Jetpack does not cache the contents of your posts and pages.

> Once I do disable Jetpack, it works as expected.

This seems like a conflict between how your code filters `the_content`, and the way one of the Jetpack features uses the same filter. I would recommend that you deactivate each Jetpack feature, one at a time, until you find the exact source of the conflict. You can then contact the Jetpack support team via [this contact form](https://jetpack.com/contact-support/?rel=support) to let them know about the conflict between the 2 plugins.

Comment: Ok, thanks ! good advice. I disabled "Publicize connections - Automatically share your posts to social networks" and it now works as expected.  Guess there is a bug in Jetpack about that, i'll contact them, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that the bug occurs when *Publicize connections* is enabled in Jetpack, thanks to the advices of @jeherve.

Indeed, I have a function hooked on `the_content` and which appends content to a specific page :

```
add_filter( 'the_content','wpsstm_frontend_wizard_content');

function wpsstm_frontend_wizard_content($content){
    if ( !is_page(MYPAGEID) ) return $content;

    ob_start();
    wpsstm_locate_template( 'frontend-wizard.php', true);
    $wizard = ob_get_clean();
    return $content . $wizard;
}
```

The template is loaded through `wpsstm_locate_template()`; which calls the core function `load_template()`:

```
/*
Locate a template & fallback in plugin's folder
*/
function wpsstm_locate_template( $template_name, $load = false, $require_once = true ) {

    if ( !$located = locate_template( 'wpsstm/' . $template_name ) ) {
        // Template not found in theme's folder, use plugin's template as a fallback
        $located = wpsstm()->plugin_dir . 'templates/' . $template_name;
    }

    if ( $load && ('' != $located) ){
        load_template( $located, $require_once );
    }

    return $located;
}
```

I fixed my problem by setting `$require_once = false` when I call *wpsstm_locate_template()* - and thus *load_template()*:

```
wpsstm_locate_template( 'frontend-wizard.php', true, false);
```

I guess that Jetpacks 'runs' my filter before it is really displayed.  Thus the file already has been loaded once and won't load again until $require_once is set to false.

I found out how to fix it but anyway, that seems to be a bug within Jetpack; or maybe I should handle this in another way. I'll write them.